# Trying to build qt creator from source with MSVC: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

Trying to build qt creator (the last available version on github) from source but having this compilation error :

```
c:\qt-creator\source\src\shared\qbs\src\shared\qtscript\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\wtf\Assertions.h(48): 
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory
```

**Qt version**: `Qt 5.13.1 msvc2017 (32bit)`

**MSVC Version**: `MSVC 2017 14.16.27023`

**Environment variables Path**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
```

Allso I have 2019 VS installed, Qt 5.13.1 msvc2017 (64bit). But error keep happening. I REALLY do not want to reinstall everything from scratch. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: If you have a version of compiler/OS that's supposed to be supported, then you should file a bug report. Also, check the existing ones if that issue has been reported. Make sure you provide exact steps to reproduce the issue and double-check those against the instructions.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt is there a list where I can check that is `If you have a version of compiler/OS that's supposed to be supported`?

Comment: I'd think that it's part of the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using wrong command prompt. I used Qt command prompt but had to use MVS command prompt.